Fully filling vector layer with polygons without dissolving the current polygons in QGIS
I have a vector containing flow paths for a specific area, with values ranging from 2-4. I want to fill in the rest of the area (to the red line boundary) with another/more polygons with a value of 1 but cannot seem to understand how to do it.


How is your red area defined ? Is it a polygon in the same layer than the other small areas ? Or from another layer ?

You could overlay your red polygon with your flowpath polygons.  In a union any polygons without the flow attributes could then be assigned a 1. There are other ways to handle the result to assign attributes.  The apparent complexity of your flow polygons may make it difficult to get the overlays to run well.  Make sure the geometry has been checked, perhaps run a v.clean before and after, topology is on and try different overlays.

@Kasper the red area is defined as the entire study area. Two different layers
